# EntiyManager CreateQuery Hangs

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I am creating a webapp with EclipseLink for the persistence layer, and I have a DAO that is hanging when I attempt to load an object.

The application/code has previously worked when loaded in to other machines/IDEs, but I have just loaded it into Eclipse Indigo on a Windows 7 machine and this error has started occuring (there are no compile errors/warnings in the code etc, and the app builds/starts fine).

The DAO method is as follows:

```
public Account loadAccountByUserName(String userName)
{
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select u from Account u where u.userName = :userName")
                .setParameter("userName", userName);

        return (Account) query.getSingleResult();
```

Now I have debugged the code, and walked through it, and once I execute the createQuery(..) line it just hangs. There are no errors, nothing logged, it just hangs (apparently indefinitely).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your box and trying it again? Could be just an issue with resources not being cleaned up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, Ok. It was just straight up slow..

Its running SpringMVC/EclipseLink app on Eclipse Indigo on a pretty new Win7 machine, connecting to a DB2 local database and it takes about 15minutes to make the first connection (following loads of data seem a lot quicker) - it just seems to be about making the connection too, as its just a user look up, and there isnt much user data in the tables.

Comment: so do you still issue the problem?