# Integration Spring Security : authentification Custom UserDetailsService

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

After having build an application using Spring MVC + Hibernate / JPA

I wanted integrate Security spring

During authentication I have a problem "no execution of query"

Here my Security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


  <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pfe.*" />



<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"></security:global-method-security>

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login?time=1">
<security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login?time=1"/>

</security:session-management>
<security:form-login 
login-page="/login" 
login-processing-url="/login.do" 
default-target-url="/home" 
always-use-default-target="true"
authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
username-parameter="username"
password-parameter="password"/>

<security:logout
logout-url="/logout"
logout-success-url="/login?out=true"
delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
invalidate-session="true"/>

<security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/home*" access="permitAll"/>

</security:http>


 <bean id="encoder"  
  class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">  
  <constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />  
 </bean> 
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService">
                <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
           </security:authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Here My LoginService

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.pfe.dao.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.pfe.entities.UserModel;
import com.pfe.services.LoginService;



@Service("loginService")
@Transactional
public class LoginServiceImp implements  UserDetailsService ,LoginService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository Repository;






        @Override
     public UserDetails loadUserByUsername( String username ) throws UsernameNotFoundException
        {
        /*  String p = "12345";
            Md5PasswordEncoder pe= new Md5PasswordEncoder();
            String encPassword =pe.encodePassword("123456",null);
        */  
             System.out.println("heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeere");
            UserModel user = Repository.findUserByUsername_isEnable(username);


            System.out.println("okkkkkkkkk");
             if( user == null )
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException( "Oops!" );

            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.println(user.getUsername());
            System.out.println(user.getPassword());
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");

            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities =  user.getListAcces_String() ;

            return new User ( user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities );
        }



}
```

And Here userRepository

```
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.pfe.dao.IDAOUser;
import com.pfe.entities.UserModel;

@Transactional
@Repository("userRepository")
public class UserRepository extends ImpJPAGenericDAO<UserModel>  implements IDAOUser {


  public UserModel findUserByUsername_isEnable(String username) {


        System.out.println("okkkkkkkkkheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeere");

        UserModel result = null ;
        TypedQuery<UserModel> query = em.createQuery("SELECT myuser FROM User myuser where myuser.username =:login",UserModel.class);

        query.setParameter("login", username);


        System.out.println("okkkkkkkkkheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeere2");





        try {
         result = query.getSingleResult() ;
        } catch (NoResultException ne){
            return null ;
        }

        return result ;
    }
```

execution :

```
heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeere
okkkkkkkkkheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeere
```

trace :

```
20:15:40,401 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:3794 - Obtaining JDBC connection
20:15:40,401 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:162 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybd?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8]
20:15:40,409 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:3794 - Obtained JDBC connection
20:15:40,409 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:3554 - initial autocommit status: true
20:15:40,409 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:3554 - disabling autocommit
20:15:40,410 DEBUG ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler:423 - Starting resource local transaction on application-managed EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@ded21c]
20:15:40,411 DEBUG ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler:400 - Joined local transaction
20:15:40,441 DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl:3799 - parse() - HQL: SELECT myuser FROM User myuser where myuser.username =:login
20:15:40,446 DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl:3554 - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  +-[FROM] Node: 'FROM'
    |  |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
    |  |     +-[IDENT] Node: 'User'
    |  |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'myuser'
    |  \-[SELECT] Node: 'SELECT'
    |     \-[IDENT] Node: 'myuser'
    \-[WHERE] Node: 'where'
       \-[EQ] Node: '='
          +-[DOT] Node: '.'
          |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'myuser'
          |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'username'
          \-[COLON] Node: ':'
             \-[IDENT] Node: 'login'

20:15:40,446 DEBUG ErrorCounter:3794 - throwQueryException() : no errors
20:15:40,474 DEBUG HqlSqlBaseWalker:3809 - select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
20:15:40,487 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:843 - Initiating transaction rollback
20:15:40,488 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:488 - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1060d0]
20:15:40,488 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:3554 - rolling back
20:15:40,488 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:3554 - rolled JDBC Connection
20:15:40,489 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:3554 - re-enabling autocommit
20:15:40,492 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:3554 - rolling back
20:15:40,493 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:3554 - rolled JDBC Connection
20:15:40,493 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:3554 - re-enabling autocommit
20:15:40,493 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:548 - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1060d0] after transaction
20:15:40,494 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils:328 - Closing JPA EntityManager
20:15:40,494 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:3794 - Releasing JDBC connection
20:15:40,494 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:3794 - Released JDBC connection
20:15:40,496 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0'
20:15:40,496 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:340 - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [SELECT myuser FROM User myuser where myuser.username =:login]
20:15:40,496 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:341 - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
20:15:40,496 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:342 - Delegating to authentication failure handlerorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@1760a96
20:15:40,497 DEBUG SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler:67 - Redirecting to /login?error=true
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you are having? What do you mean by "no execution of query"? What is happening? What do you expect to happen? Do you get a result back? Do you get a stacktrace (if so can you provide a complete one)?

Comment: I haven't got neither a result nor an error ,  It stops at this line 'TypedQuery<UserModel> query = em.createQuery("SELECT myuser FROM User myuser where myuser.username =:login",UserModel.class);

        query.setParameter("login", username);'

Comment: If you enable debug logging for Hibernate what do you see in the logs at this point? Are you sure it isn't just really slow? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914271/entiymanager-createquery-hangs

Comment: Do you see any hibernate logging (if not you haven't configured logging correctly)? Please post the hibernate logs. What happens if you change the creation of the Query to create a query for a different domain object? What does UserModel look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the logs it is not "stopping", but throwing an Exception. The logs state:

```
20:15:40,496 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:340 - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [SELECT myuser FROM User myuser where myuser.username =:login]
```

Specifically:

> QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [SELECT myuser FROM User
>   myuser where myuser.username =:login]

My guess is that you meant to use UserModel within the query rather than User. Specifically you should use the following within your UserRepository:

```
TypedQuery<UserModel> query = em.createQuery("SELECT myuser FROM UserModel myuser where myuser.username =:login",UserModel.class);
```

Comment: Thanks !!  am beginner :(

Comment: @LhbLaura No problem. If you don't like doing JPA manually, you might consider using Spring Data JPA which will automatically create your queries (including paging, sorting, and custom properties) for you using some conventions. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ If you are doing REST you can also add a simple annotation and it will be exposed as REST endpoint with Spring Data REST http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/